# how do i search a specific field in textfile?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

i want to search field 5 of the text file, whether it is "Salaried", "Commission" or "Hourly"
after searching it will store the data found in type. then will categorize into which type the Person is in and run the code accordingly to the type.
I am stuck because i did not know how to use the search function and store it in a temporary field.

code:

```
        payroll()
        {
          line=`grep -i "^${update_empID}," $data`
          empID=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f1`
          name=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f2`
          job=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f3`
          phone=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f4` 
          type=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f5`

           clear
           echo -e "Enter the pay"
           echo -en "Enter ID: "
           read empid_search

           #Check if particular entry to search for existed to perform deletion
           if [ `count_lines "^${empid_search},"` -eq 0 ]
           then
               echo "Error: This particular record does not exist!!"
           else
               echo "Please verify update of this employee's record: " #Prompt for confirmation of employee details
            echo
               echo "Employee's Details: "
               locate_lines "^${empid_search},"   #Find location of the entry     
               awk -F ',' '$5 == "Salaried Employee"' $PAYROLL > types

           if [$type="Salaried"]
           then
            echo "$name is a Salaried"
            echo "Enter Salary :"
            read salary

          if [$type="Hourly"]
           then
            echo "$name is a Hourly"
            echo "Enter employee's Hourly Wage :"
                        read hourly_wage
                        echo "Enter hours worked this week :"
                        read hours_worked



             echo "${empID},${name},${job},${phone},${Type},${salary}" >> tmpfile ; mv tmpfile $data
               echo " particulars has been updated!!"
               fi      
            else
            echo "f"     
           fi

        }

count_lines()
{
   grep -i "$@" $PAYROLL | wc -l            
}
#Function to locate lines that match $1
locate_lines()
{
  result=-1
  if [ ! -z "$1" ]
  then
     grep -i "$@" $PAYROLL    
     result=$?  #Returns 0 if previous command is successful
  fi
  return $result   
}
```

text file

```
3,Frak,IT,9765753,Salaried
1,May,CEO,9789292,Salaried
5,Samy,Sales user,92221312,Commission
2,Orange,cleaner,935233233,Hourly
```

Answer (score 0):

> `i want to search field 5 of the text file, whether it is "Salaried", "Commission" or "Hourly"`

You should use awk like this:

```
awk -F ',' '$5 ~ (Salaried|Commission|Hourly) {print}' file
```

btw your BASH script has many syntax errors and if you switch to awk it will be far more easier to write your script.

[**Awk tutorial**](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: hey, sorry i did not paste the full code here. i've tried using awk
awk -F ',' '$5 == "Salaried Employee"' $PAYROLL > types
but it doesn't seems to work well too.

Comment: @Alien: If you post your awk script, we'll help you fix it.

Comment: i've edited it, is it clearer now ? sorry for the unclear question

Comment: sry missed that out, updated `count_lines` and `locate_lines`